# I can not run `fwupdmgr` on my system

Tags: services, fwupd

Whenever I try to run `fwupdmgr` on my system (either as root or a regular user), I receive the following error message:

```
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.fwupd: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd': timed out
```

This problem just seemed to develop out of nowhere, and is causing some significant worry as it's preventing me from grabbing some security updates for my computer's BIOS.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with `fwupd` version `0.7.0-0ubuntu4.3` installed on my system. I am also aware of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888882/cannot-update-fwupd), but it is currently unanswered and my system does not have `fwupd` running at startup.

What is going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Weird... Someone has already voted to close this question as 'unclear', I wonder if it's the same person doing that to so many other questions suddenly for no apparent good reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve my own problem in a very odd way. After doing a bit of digging into services, I discovered a binary: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fwupd/fwupd`.

Upon running this manually, I received the following error message:

```
(fwupd:32140): Fu-WARNING **: FuMain: failed to load AppStream data: AppStream metadata name /var/cache/app-info/xmls/.goutputstream-PY2M1Y not valid, expected .xml[.*] or .yml[.*]
```

Deleting the file mentioned like so:

```
rm /var/cache/app-info/xmls/.goutputstream-PY2M1Y
```

solved my problem, and I can update my system firmware yet again.